# How does the outcome of a case affect the rest of the game?

Tags: sherlock-holmes

Solving a case in Sherlock Holmes: Crimes and Punishments doesn't tell you directly whether your suspect was guilty or not guilty. However, you can choose to see the real outcome of the case but the game issues a warning that this might *"spoil the game experience"*.

Does this mean that there will be some connection in between the several cases? Or am I supposed to never reveal the true culprit of the crimes?

Answer (score 2):

Peeking at the solution at the end is just that - a way for the player to check if they got all the clues and made the right choice.

Depending on the outcome and whether you choose Absolve or Condemn, you will receive some form of correspondence on your letter pile related to the case. Apart from that, there are no obvious plot changes.

I played through and chose different paths, having interpreted a tool tip hinting that "actions now will have repercussions later". To my disappointment, there was nothing new. I just received a few different letters.